# How can I fix an unrecognized class issue?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android app and I created java folders to organize my code. So I clean and rebuild project and included imports into every of my classes. because now the path to the classes have changed. I thought android studio could detect this and fix the import automatically. But since then is giving all sort of errors when using another class within my project. let's take for example the following line of code inside one of my classes that uses another class inside the "activity" folder.

```
Intent BookScanIntent = new Intent(AllScanActivity.this, org.pctechtips.netdroid.activity.BookScanActivity.class);
```

I have to include the full path to the activity, and even then it will not recognize the class. I have to constantly rebuild my project to fix this errors. but this one will not find the activity/class. I get error

```
error: cannot find symbol class BookScanActivity
```

this is the structure of my project
activity, dbhelper, runnables
Both the BookScanActivity and AllScanActivity are inside "activity" directory. How can I fix all my imports so I don't have to correct this all the time. and instead of using full path eg: org.pctechtips.netdroid..blah.blah... I just can use the name of the class?
Also, I noticed after I orginazed my code inside directories the gradle now has an entry

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/org/pctechtips/netdroid/runnable', 'src/main/java/org/pctechtips/netdroid/adapters', 'src/main/java/org/pctechtips/netdroid/dbhelper', 'src/main/java/org/pctechtips/netdroid/classes', 'src/main/java/org/pctechtips/netdroid/activity']
        }
    }
```

the path seem to be correct, so why is not working? Thanks

Comment: Try to remove the package with class name  org.pctechtips.netdroid.activity.BookScanActivity.class , and Import again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the whole `sourceSets` configuration, because all but the first entry is non-sense (and this one is the default configuration) - and then click on whatever class-name is red in the Java code and hit `<Alt> + <Enter>` (or `<option> + <Enter>` on a Mac) to add an `import` for that class.

Also see [Mastering IntelliJ IDEA keyboard shortcuts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html).

Comment: If the OP is on Mac OS it should be `<option> + <Enter>`.